# ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector"div[class='card-content""

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have a script that crawl a website data and i try it on **jupyter NoteBook** it work and return the expected result but when i try it on the **visual studio code** editor the system crash and display the below error:

```
 File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1426, in select
    'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "div[class='card-content"
```

where is the error and how to fix it ?

## code:

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get("https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-chef-jobs/").content,
    "lxml"
)


links = []
for a in soup.select("h2.m0.t-regular a"):
    if a['href'] not in links:
        links.append("https://www.bayt.com"+ a['href'])
joineddd = []

for link in links:
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
    jobdesc=s.select_one("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] p")

    alldt = [dt.text for dt in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dt")]
    dt_Job_location =              alldt[0]
    dt_Job_Company_Industry =      alldt[1]
    dt_Job_Company_Type =          alldt[2]
    if len(alldt[3])>0:
        dt_Job_Job_Role =              alldt[3]
    elif len(dt_Job_Employment_Type)>0:
        dt_Job_Employment_Type =       alldt[4]
            
    alldt.append("link")
    alldt.append("description")
    
    
    alldd = [dd.text for dd in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dd")]
    dd_job_location =             alldd[0]
    dd_job_Company_Industry =     alldd[1]
    dd_job_Company_Type =         alldd[2]
    if len(alldd[3])>0:
        dd_job_Job_Role =             alldd[3]
    elif len(dd_job_Employment_Type)>0:
        dd_job_Employment_Type =      alldd[4]
    
    alldd.insert(0,link)
    alldd.insert(1,jobdesc)
    joineddd.append(alldd)
    
    print("-" * 80)
```

On the jupyter NoteBook  the script run and finish by printing dashes

on the editor the system crash.

Comment: I suggest you check the versions being used in each environment and add them to the question, e.g. beautifulsoup, requests, python

Comment: I have run your code in pycharm editor and it's working fine. There is no issue with jupyter NoteBook and any other editor. Something else is wrong with your environment setup.

Comment: @MartinEvans versions of what ?? i did not understand your comment

Comment: Add something like `import bs4, sys; print([requests.__version__, bs4.__version__, sys.version])` to the top of your script

Comment: you were right i wasn't running my virtual env